# VueJs post with Axios. err var is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

i m have this code

```js
<script>
import axios from 'axios';
class Local {
    constructor(adress, city, contact){
        this.adress = adress;
        this.city = city;
        this.contact = contact;
    }
}
export default {
  data(){
      return{
          local: new Local()
      }
  },
    methods:{ 
        addLocal(){
            axios.post("http://localhost:3000/api/local",{
                local: new Local()    
            })
            .then(res => console.log(JSON.res))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
            local = new Local();
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

```html
<form @submit.prevent="addLocal">
                            <div class="form-input">
                                <input type="text" v-model="local.adress" class="form-control" placeholder="Adress">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-input">
                                <input type="text" v-model="local.city" class="form-control" placeholder="City">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-input">
                                <input type="text" v-model='local.contact' class="form-control" placeholder="Contact">
                            </div>
                            <br>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary  btn-block">Ready.</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Cancel</button>
                        </form>
```

This problem is some like this can recognize local from de class, is something wrong???
is best maybe using vue-resource for this?
im open mind with the responses. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are executing new Local(), you need to pass parameter to it.
so the object which will be created will have defined properties.

```
new Local('my address', 'my city', 'my contact')
```